# Spring boot with elastic fail while index exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm trying to connect a Spring boot application with ElasticSearch, but I get the next error:

Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Error while for indexExists request: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.GetIndexRequest

Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.repository")
public class ESConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()  
            .connectedTo("ElasticSearch Server")
            .withBasicAuth("user", "password").build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();                         
    }

}
```

Entity :

```
@Document(indexName = "flight")
public class FlightPositionES {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String ident;
    private String airGround;
    private Double altitude;
    private Integer clock;
    private String flightId;
    private Double groundSpeed;
    private Double heading;
    private GeoPoint location;
    private String aircraftRegistration;
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface IFlightPositionESRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<FlightPositionES, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the:
ES server : "https://cluster:port"
and that was my fault
To correct that I used
ES Server: "cluster:port"
and added usingSsl() method

`final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()   .connectedTo("ES server") .withBasicAuth("user", "password").build();`